# How to change stdin when using Runtime class in JAVA

Tags: java, inputstream, stdin, bufferedimage, outputstream

I want to use tesseract to recognize some text and I will use `Runtime` class to exec system command. Here, I want to use stdin to input my img ,rather than reading a file.

```java
    private String preprocessCmdCommand(BufferedImage img) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String cmd = "D:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe stdin output -l chi_sm";
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p = run.exec(cmd);
            // Write to the standard input stream
            OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
            stdin.write(HelpFunction.getImageBinary(img, "png")); //(TesseractOcr.java:40)
            InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
            consumeInputStream(stdout);

            if (p.waitFor() != 0) {
                if (p.exitValue() == 1)
                    System.err.println("fail!");
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried the method suggested by the first answer , but I got an exception .

```java
java.io.IOException: pipe is closing
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108)
    at ocr_processor.TesseractOcr.preprocessCmdCommand(TesseractOcr.java:40)
    at ocr_processor.TesseractOcr.recognizeSingleText(TesseractOcr.java:57)
    at Test.testOrientFunction(Test.java:32)
    at Test.main(Test.java:42)
[INFO ] 2020-07-16 08:57:42,783 method:Test.testOrientFunction(Test.java:32)
```

My platform is windows 10 , Java SDK is 14.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well today I get an idea from other questions. I finally use the following code to achieve my target!

```java
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process process = runtime.exec("cmd /c tesseract stdin stdout");
            OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
            os.write(util.HelpFunction.getBinaryImage(img));
            os.close();
            consumeInputStream(process.getInputStream());
            int exitVal = process.exitValue();
            System.out.println("process exit value is " + exitVal);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks for helping me !  :)

Answer (score 1):

When you start a process, the [Process.getOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--) method returns a stream that writes to the standard input stream of the process.

```
Process p = ...
OutputStream stdin=p.getOutputStream();
// Write to the standard input stream
stdin.write(...);
```

The ProcessBuilder class gives you more control: you can connect the stdin to a file for example.

Comment: I tried your method ,but I get an Exception called `java.io.IOException: pipe is being closed`.
Is there anything wrong?

Comment: please add the details of the exception (stack trace and which line threw it) and the related code to the question. Also, which operating system you are using

Comment: I have changed the description of my question , Is there anything wrong for my code ?

Comment: This sounds like a Windows specific problem, and I don't know that much about how inter process communication with pipes works on windows. Maybe there is a limit to how much data you can write in a pipe without reading. Maybe tesseract crashed. As a workaround you could try saving the image in a temporary file, and making tesseract read the file.

Comment: I tried the same script on Ubuntu and it works , so it may be the difference between different platform . And I found JAVA is somewhat complex for a newcomer such as me .       :(